How to integrate wagtail 6.1 with django improved user
I was using django-improved-user with Wagtail (up to Wagtail 6.0) and things were working fairly well. With Wagtail 6.1 now, the user listing page errors out because it is trying to order the listing by first name and last name, but the default user model supplied by django improved user does not have those fields. It instead uses full name and short name. Is there a simple way to customize the user listing page to determine which columns to use and how to specify the ordering?
